# Start a test case from TFS 2013

Tags: manual-testing, tfs

In TFS 2013.3 I have a Feature that has a few Test Cases linked to it under the Test Cases tab. If I double-click any of the cases they open, but in editing mode - I can add new steps and edit existing ones.

How do I start running the test like I can from the a test suite or is that not possible?

Also, what's the best approach for testing a feature during implementation, QA, and regression with the help of TFS... How to best organize the test cases? Test plan for each epic and test suites for each feature?

Comment: Hope this help you : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380763.aspx

Comment: It does help, it would be great to understand what's the best approach for testing a feature during implementation, QA, and regression... How to best create the test cases? I would accept an answer that explains this.

Comment: For that can you please update your question? So I can post answer.

Comment: Expanded the question...

Comment: Yes, I have posted answer.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About TFS :**

It is obvious that when you click on already created test case , It will allow you to Edit/Modify that test case and then you able to save it.

To know how to create new test case please refer : [Create Test Case in TFS-2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380763.aspx)

**About Test case approach :**

TFS will just help you to insert test cases , edit/update it. To test things you can do manual testing OR Automation testing for created test cases.

If your project is very long term and huge with lots of functions & you have expanded testing team then only better you create test plan otherwise you can create direct test cases.

Test cases depends on functionality you are testing like login , register , add to cart. Each function have diff. test case. Best test case fields are

1 - Test case ID

2 - Test case Name

3 - Step/Action

4 - Expected Result

5 - Actual Result

If you automate test cases by script[Like Selenium web driver] then your Regression & Retesting will be easy , fast and accurate.